# Receive a file with Drupal 7

Tags: 7, files, services

I have a java application that will send a CSV file to a Drupal 7 site through using POST method.

how i receive file on drupal side by using custom module

I need to parse the file to add data into a custom table.

Comment: you can try with services module

Comment: I second the services module, here is a PHP gist on uploading file: https://gist.github.com/MuhammadReda/e2fee99a2469bc324f38 - just watch out to get the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` set right.  Depending how secure it needs to be session based authentication is fairly straightforward.  Then you could use `hook_file_insert` to add your custom meta data.

Answer (score 1):

I will try again:

you can `var_dump($_POST);` to get all posted variables on the site and know the array index in which your application POST's

Comment: According to your answer I made a custom web service to do this :)

Comment: @Promo You've made a REST cliënt in Java to be precise.

Comment: No I didn't work on java side, only Drupal. So a made a simple page that is called by a POST with http authentication. Then I parse the file and add data to the database :)